# Convert gif to have only global palette

Tags: gif

In a UI library for resource constrained embedded devices I would like to create an optimized GIF decoder. The goal is to store the decoded image in indexed format. To do so the GIF needs to have only a global palette and no local palettes on each frame. (With local palettes a completely different palette can be used if only smaller areas of the GIF is updated on a frame.)

So the question is: how can I convert a GIF file to use only a global palette. I know that it can result in color loss, but it's an acceptable trade off.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing#advanced-gif-encoder-with-high-color-support) library (disclaimer: the author is me) allows you to re-save an animated GIF with just a single palette.

##### 1. Specific solution for `System.Drawing.Bitmap`

If you use GDI+ on Windows, then the simplest solution is to use the dedicated [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.Drawing) because it has higher-level methods that make the conversion really simple:

```cs
// obtain the original GIF with possibly per-frame local palette
using var myOriginalGif = new Bitmap(thePathForMyHighColorAnimatedGif);

// extracting the frames
Bitmap[] frames = myOriginalGif.ExtractBitmaps();

// save a new animated GIF with a fix palette
frames.SaveAsAnimatedGif(outputPath,
    delay: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), // now using a constant delay
    quantizer: PredefinedColorsQuantizer.SystemDefault8BppPalette(), // the web-safe palette
    ditherer: OrderedDitherer.Bayer8x8); // optional
```

Of course, the example above has a disadvantage that [ExtractBitmaps](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_BitmapExtensions_ExtractBitmaps.htm) does not retrieve the delays information between the frames so you need to come up with some custom delay that you can pass to the [SaveAsAnimatedGif](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/Overload_KGySoft_Drawing_ImageExtensions_SaveAsAnimatedGif.htm) overloads.

The key for your goal is the `quantizer` parameter. In the example I used the [SystemDefault8BppPalette](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_PredefinedColorsQuantizer_SystemDefault8BppPalette.htm), which uses the standard web-safe palette but you can use any other custom fix palette by the [FromCustomPalette](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/Overload_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_PredefinedColorsQuantizer_FromCustomPalette.htm) method. If you don't specify this parameter, then an [OptimizedPaletteQuantizer](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/T_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_OptimizedPaletteQuantizer.htm) instance will be used that allows creating a local palette for each frames.

The `ditherer` argument is optional, it just helps preserving the details better. In the example I used an [OrderedDitherer](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/T_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_OrderedDitherer.htm) but for the best quality you can use an [ErrorDiffusionDitherer](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/T_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_ErrorDiffusionDitherer.htm), though it's a bit slower.

##### 2. General solution for any other environment

If you can't (or don't want to) use `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, then you can use your favorite environment that has a GIF decoder to obtain the frames. To be able to use my [`GifEncoder`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/T_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_GifEncoder.htm) class from the technology-independent [core package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.Drawing.Core/) you need to access the frames as [`IReadableBitmapData`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/T_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_IReadableBitmapData.htm) instances.

- If you use WPF/UWP/WinUI/SkiaSharp, then you can do it easily by by using one of the [environment-specific packages](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing#available-packages): you only need to use the corresponding `GetReadableBitmapData` extension for the specific bitmap type (eg. `WritableBitmap` or SkiaSharp's `SKBitmap`, etc.).
- If you use [any other environment](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing#3rd-party-bitmap-types-support) you can use the `BitmapDataFactory` class to obtain a bitmap data for the frames. For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75534943/5114784) is how you can do it for ImageSharp bitmaps.

And once you have the frames then you can simply use the [`EncodeAnimation`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_GifEncoder_EncodeAnimation.htm) where the configuration's [Quantizer](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/P_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_AnimatedGifConfiguration_Quantizer.htm) should be set as described at solution 1.

##### 3. Tool-based solution

If you don't want to convert your GIF programmatically, then you can use Nicke Manarin's excellent tool, [ScreenToGif](https://github.com/NickeManarin/ScreenToGif), which also contains my GIF encoder. This is the simplest solution if want to preserve the original delays for the frames.

Just load the original GIF in the Editor, click on Save As, and select the GIF format and KGy SOFT encoder. In fact, it has a predefined 'Low quality' preset, which uses the same fixed web-safe palette and ordered dithering demonstrated in solution 1.

[image: ScreenToGif KGy SOFT GIF Encoder]

A possible example:

| Original high color GIF | Conversion result with web-safe palette and ordered dithering |
| --- | --- |
| [image: High color GIF animation] | [image: Converted GIF animation with a global palette] |